# Concatenate two dataframes of different sizes (pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes with unique `id`s. They share some columns but not all. I need to create a combined dataframe which will include rows from missing `id`s from the second dataframe. Tried merge and concat, no luck. It's probably too late, my brain stopped working. Will appreciate your help!

```
   df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'id': ['a','b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m'],
        'metric1': [123,22,356,412,54,634,72,812,129,110,200],
        'metric2':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
        })


df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['a','b','c','d','f','g','h','q','z','w'],
    'metric1': [123,22,356,412,54,634,72,812,129,110]
    })
df2
```

The result should look like this:

```
    id  metric1 metric2
0   a   123     1.0
1   b   22      2.0
2   c   356     3.0
3   d   412     4.0
4   f   54      5.0
5   g   634     6.0
6   h   72      7.0
7   j   812     8.0
8   k   129     9.0
9   l   110     10.0
10  m   200     11.0
11  q   812     NaN
12  z   129     NaN
13  w   110     NaN
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case using `combine_first`

```
df1.set_index('id').combine_first(df2.set_index('id')).reset_index()
Out[766]: 
   id  metric1  metric2
0   a    123.0      1.0
1   b     22.0      2.0
2   c    356.0      3.0
3   d    412.0      4.0
4   f     54.0      5.0
5   g    634.0      6.0
6   h     72.0      7.0
7   j    812.0      8.0
8   k    129.0      9.0
9   l    110.0     10.0
10  m    200.0     11.0
11  q    812.0      NaN
12  w    110.0      NaN
13  z    129.0      NaN
```

Comment: Thank you. Perfect!